# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) - wordpress

Tags: wordpress

On my WordPress website I am getting following error message... 
""Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)""

My website - hindi.NewBuzzIndia.com

Can any one help me...?

Comment: When you do get error msg...?? even its opening great.

Comment: Your website is working. Please post your exact problem.